# how to get year from datefield at django?

Tags: python, django

i want to get year from birthday.
so i use self.birthday.year
but it make error.
how do i fix it?

best regards.

```
class User(AbstractUser):

# First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns
# around the globe.

name = models.CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255) #이름
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES_GENDER) # 성
birthday = models.DateField(null=True) #생일

def calculate_age(self):
    import datetime
    return int((datetime.date.year - self.birthday.year) +1)

 age = property(calculate_age) #나이
```

Comment: The correct code should be return int((datetime.datetime.now().year - self.birthday.year +1)

Comment: @serbia99 thank you very much

Comment: Please give a proper error description including the error traceback!

Comment: What if the `birthday` is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution,

```
from datetime import date


class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES_GENDER)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True)

    @property
    def calculate_age(self):
        if self.birthday:
            today = date.today()
            return today.year - self.birthday.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.birthday.month, self.birthday.day))
        return 0  # when "self.birthday" is "NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `datetime.date.year` does not exists. You can fetch the `year` of a `date` (or `datetime`) object with `.year`, and you can thus for example use `today()` or `now()`.

Semantically the function is incorrect as well. If I am born in 1984, then I am not per se 35 years old: that depends on whether the current year is before or after the day of birth (for example February 9th).

Finally there can be an error if the `self.birthday` value is `None`. In that case you probably want to return `None` as well.

So a potential solution for this is:

```
from datetime import date

class User(AbstractUser):

    # ...

    def calculate_age(self):
        bd = self.birthday
        if bd:
            td = date.today()
            return td.year - bd.year - ((td.month, td.day) < (bd.month, bd.day))
```

We thus first calculate `today()`, and then we return the current year minus the year of the birthday and minus one if today is still before the birthday this year.

In case the user did *not* specify his/her birthday, then the `calculate_age(..)` will return `None` (a value that can be interpreted as "unknown").

An issue that still remains (and is harder to fix) are timezones: since `today` in Australia is another `today` than in the United States, it is possible that - depending on where the server and users are located - the age of a user is one too high the day before his/her birthday, or one too low one day on his/her birthday. This is a harder problem to solve, since we have no information here where the user is located.